# Asynchronous ReadDirectoryChangesW()?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, winapi

I want to monitor the modifications in a specified directory, and retrieve the exact change information. So I've decided to use the [ReadDirectoryChangesW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx) function. But I want to use it asynchronously, which means I don't want my worker thread to be blocked if there are no changes in the directory.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` with an I/O Completion Port, which is good for when you want to monitor multiple directories because you can have a single thread servicing the IOCP and dealing with the results from all of your calls to ReadDirectoryChangesW().

First create an IOCP, once, by calling `CreateIoCompletionPort()`. Start a thread that calls `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` and deals with your async directory changes.

Now for each directory that you want to monitor. First, open your directory handle as normal. Next, associate it with your IOCP by calling `CreateIoCompletionPort()` and passing the IOCP handle in (see docs for more details). Finally, call `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` and pass an `OVERLAPPED` as detailed in the docs. The call will return, and if successful, the results will become available as the results of `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()` in the thread that you created to service the IOCP.

Comment: Thank you! I want to use completion routine. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Another question is, how can I retrieve the change information from GetQueuedCompletionStatus() method? Is it included in the OVERLAPPED structure?

Comment: I've not used completion routines as they're more complex to use as you need to ensure that the thread that calls ReadDirectoryChangesW() is in an alertable wait state...

Comment: What I do is create a class that inherits from OVERLAPPED and contains a buffer for the data. I then create one of these per watch and pass it to ReadDirectoryChangesW(). When GetQueuedCompletionStatus() returns you have a pointer to the class and can access the data just as if you made a sync call.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/950/CDirectoryChangeWatcher-ReadDirectoryChangesW-all

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN documentation for ReadDirectoryChnagesW()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx):

> For asynchronous completion, you can receive notification in one of
>   three ways:
>
> - Using the GetOverlappedResult function. To receive notification
>     through GetOverlappedResult, do not
>     specify a completion routine in the
>     lpCompletionRoutine parameter. Be sure
>     to set the hEvent member of the
>     OVERLAPPED structure to a unique
>     event.
> - Using the GetQueuedCompletionStatus function. To
>     receive notification through
>     GetQueuedCompletionStatus, do not
>     specify a completion routine in
>     lpCompletionRoutine. Associate the
>     directory handle hDirectory with a
>     completion port by calling the
>     CreateIoCompletionPort function.
> - Using a completion routine. To receive notification through a
>     completion routine, do not associate
>     the directory with a completion port.
>     Specify a completion routine in
>     lpCompletionRoutine. This routine is
>     called whenever the operation has been
>     completed or canceled while the thread
>     is in an alertable wait state. The
>     hEvent member of the OVERLAPPED
>     structure is not used by the system,
>     so you can use it yourself.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm a little confused by what MSDN says. Can you explain a little more?

Comment: I want to know which method is better if I want to monitor more than one directory simultaneously in a single thread.