# c++ ReadDirectoryChangesW on directory with symlinks for Directories

Tags: c++, createfile, readdirectorychangesw

I have an application which I use to monitor file/dir changes within a directory. However, this directory also contains `symlinks` to other directories (which are accessible). However, when I modify a `file` within a `symlink` directory, the notification is ***not*** triggered. E.g. when I monitor `Root`:

```
--Root
  --Dir
    --File1 //Trigger works
  --SDir(Symlink dir)
    --File2 //Trigger won't work
```

However, when I monitor `Root/SDir`, which is the symlink directory than the trigger on File2 works correctly. E.g.:

```
--SDir
  --File2 //Trigger works
```

So when the `symlink directory` is not the root, it won't trigger on file changes within that directory. However, when I set the `symlink directory` as the root, it works fine. And yes, the `bWatchSubtree` parameter within the `ReadDirectoryChangesW-function` is set to `true`.

For the good order, I open the directory handle using the `CreateFile` function:

```
CreateFile(
    Dir, //Root or Root/SDir in this example
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    NULL);
```

So, why won't the trigger work on files within symlinks if that same symlink is not the root of `ReadDirectoryChangesW`?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @BenVoigt, yes obviously right? Why won't the trigger work on files within symlinks if that same symlink is not the root of `ReadDirectoryChangesW `

Comment: Because you aren't watching the directory that contains the files?  You can reach the files through the symlink, but they aren't inside the directory you are watching (well, unless the symlink points to another directory under your watched directory -- and then the events will report the real path, not the path going through the symlink).

Comment: Right, do you have any solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: Look for symlinks inside your watched directory, and create an additional watch for the directory each symlink points to?

Comment: @BenVoigt, right good solution. However, I thought it was impossible to have multiple watches within the same application at the same time? Your answer makes me think that my assumptions are incorrect?

Comment: I've definitely seen applications that watch multiple directories simultaneously.  I don't see any restriction documented preventing multiple watches, and if there is one, it might only affect `FindFirstChangeNotification` but not `ReadDirectoryChanges` (or vice versa).

Comment: This [official example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) demonstrates two simultaneous watches.

Comment: Right, thanks for the heads-up but will this also give me back the filepaths?

Comment: That particular example won't, because it uses `FindFirstChangeNotification`.  If you use multiple watches with `ReadDirectoryChanges` you should get the additional information.  Note you either need to use OVERLAPPED or multiple threads, maybe using blocking `ReadDirectoryChanges` is what caused you to believe there can only be one at once.

Comment: @BenVoigt, right I would like to use `ReadDirectoryChanges`. I also assumed it was impossible since I can't find an example online watching two or more directories at the same time. Could you give me an example of `ReadDirectoryChanges` monitoring two directories at the same time? **SIDENOTE** _I need the entire path that has been modified, so not only the relative name from that currently watched directory. How will I manage this with multiple threads?_

Comment: Not an example, but this clearly says that it's possible to watch multiple directories with `ReadDirectoryChanges`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/339989/103167

Comment: I tend to prefer OVERLAPPED rather than multiple threads, but either will work.  With multiple threads, each root directory will wake up a different thread.  With OVERLAPPED, each root directory will set a different event handle.  Either way, that lets you match the event to the `ReadDirectoryChanges` call, and thus know in which area the change occurs.

Comment: @BenVoigt, right you have lost me here. I have no idea how I can accomplish this. A simple example would help a lot

Comment: What is the current structure of your code? Console application or GUI? 
Are you already creating a thread to wait on one directory? It sounds like the problem you have is not how to call `ReadDirectoryWatcher`, but how to perform multiple I/O operations at once.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I have a Console Application. Indeed I have the `ReadDirectoryWatcher ` up and running on one directory which works great (except for symlinks within the directories). However, I have no idea how to perform these multiple I/O operations at once...

Comment: Ok, if you have a single-threaded console app, you *definitely* don't want to introduce multiple threads.  If you ask a question about how to watch multiple directories at once using ReadDirectoryChanges inside a console app, I'll answer with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I would like to follow the step-by-step instructions since I definitely don't want to use multiple threads if not necessary.

Comment: I've added wtach to every single folder of entire trees before, using the OVERLAPPED method.  I had it set up so I'd only have to wait on the root folder of the tree, then walk my subfolders' events with `WaitForSingleObject(h, 0);`  to locate the folder that had changed.  That works fine.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy, great! Could you provide me with an example?

Comment: Well, I have a working example of watching an array of directories, but no place to put it, because you haven't asked a question about watching multiple trees.  It wouldn't be a complete answer to this question, because it doesn't care if the directory names came from symlinks.

Comment: @BenVoigt, could you please show me your code or talk me through it? That is exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: if you want spy changing inside directory  create class which encapsulate directory handle and any data which you need for this folder (say it path), open folder with overlaped flag, call `BindIoCompletionCallback` on handle and you will be receiver notification, until close handle. want several folders - simply create several instance of this class

Comment: @RbMm, could you provide me with an example?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - of course, 15 min

Comment: @RbMm, great, thanks. In the meantime I will try to read some docs about I/O to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to set up watch over an entire tree...  These are excepts from my code base, I can't put the entire code here because of dependencies...

Usage:

```
   FolderWatchInfo fwi;
   fwi.Create(strRootPath,  TRUE, 
        FolderWatchInfo::flagDirWatch | FolderWatchInfo::flagFileWatch);

    WaitForSingleObject(fwi.GetHandle(), INFINITE);  // or the usual WaitForMultipleObjects(...)
                                                     // with an exit event
    //...
    //On event signaled:

    CStringsVector vFolders;
    fwi.GetSubDirChangeList(vFolders);
    Sleep(1000);        // give a little time for things to settle...

    for each (const CIRString& str in vFolders)
    {
       OnFolderChange(str);  // signal my app
    }
```

Events are automatic reset, so there's no maintenance to do on that.

Stuff that's not there:

CIRSingleLock is like lock_guard

DirScanner is a wrapper around FindFirstFile(), it reports folders to the Reader struct.

include file:

```
// *********************************************************************************************************************************
// *********************************************************************************************************************************

#pragma once

#include <DirScanner.h>
#include <shared_ptr.h>
#include <boost/weak_ptr.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <IRSingleLock.h>

// *********************************************************************************************************************************
// *********************************************************************************************************************************

class FolderWatchInfo
{
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public:
    enum Flags
    {
        flagFileCreateDelete  = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME,
        flagFileModify        = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
        flagFileSecurity      = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
        flagFileAttributes    = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES,
        flagDirCreateDetelete = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME,

        flagFileWatch = flagFileCreateDelete | flagFileModify,
        flagDirWatch  = flagDirCreateDetelete,
    };

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    typedef shared_ptr<FolderWatchInfo> FolderWatchInfoPtr;
    typedef std::vector<FolderWatchInfoPtr> FWIVector;
    typedef std::vector<CIRString> CStringsVector;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private:
    struct Reader : public DirScanner::Reader
    {
        FolderWatchInfo& fwi;

        Reader(FolderWatchInfo& fwi_) 
            : DirScanner::Reader(fwi_.GetPathName(), _T("__NOFILES__"), 1)
            ,  fwi(fwi_)
        { }

        virtual bool OnDirectoryFound(LPCTSTR szPathName, const WIN32_FIND_DATA& findData)
        {
            FolderWatchInfoPtr p = make_shared<FolderWatchInfo>();
            p->Create(fwi.GetPathName() + _T("\\") + szPathName, fwi.GetFlags());
            fwi.m_vChildren.push_back(p);
            return TRUE;
        }
    };

    friend struct Reader;

private:
    CIRCriticalSection m_lock;
    weak_ptr<FolderWatchInfo> m_pParent;
    CIRString m_strPathName;
    HANDLE m_hWatchEvent;
    DWORD m_dwFlags;
    FWIVector m_vChildren;

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

private:
    inline FolderWatchInfo(const FolderWatchInfo&) {}
    inline bool operator = (const FolderWatchInfo&) {}

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public:
    FolderWatchInfo();
    ~FolderWatchInfo();

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    HANDLE Create(const CIRString& strPathName, BOOL bRecursive, DWORD dwFlags);
    void CloseHandle();
    void ResetEvent();

protected:
    HANDLE Create(const CIRString& strPathName, DWORD dwFlags);
    void AddToSubDirChangeList(CStringsVector& vSubDirs);

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public:
    inline HANDLE GetHandle() const
    {
        return m_hWatchEvent;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline void GetSubDirChangeList(CStringsVector& vSubDirs)
    {
        CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);
        vSubDirs.clear();
        AddToSubDirChangeList(vSubDirs);
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline FolderWatchInfoPtr GetParent() const
    {
        return FolderWatchInfoPtr(m_pParent, boost::detail::sp_nothrow_tag());
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline const FWIVector& GetChildren() const
    {
        return m_vChildren;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline const CIRString& GetPathName() const
    {
        return m_strPathName;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline DWORD GetFlags() const
    {
        return m_dwFlags;
    }

    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    inline bool operator == (LPCTSTR szPath)
    {
        return (m_strPathName.CompareNoCase(szPath) == 0);
    }
};

// ***************************************************************************************************************************** EOF
```

cpp.

```
// *********************************************************************************************************************************
// *********************************************************************************************************************************

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "FolderWatchInfo.h"

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

FolderWatchInfo::FolderWatchInfo()
    : m_hWatchEvent(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    , m_dwFlags(0)
{ }

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

FolderWatchInfo::~FolderWatchInfo(void)
{
    CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);
    if (m_hWatchEvent != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FindCloseChangeNotification(m_hWatchEvent);
    }
}

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

HANDLE FolderWatchInfo::Create(const CIRString& strPathName, BOOL bRecursive, DWORD dwFlags)
{
    CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);

    ASSERT(m_hWatchEvent == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    m_strPathName = CleanPathName(strPathName);
    m_dwFlags = dwFlags;
    m_hWatchEvent = FindFirstChangeNotification(m_strPathName, bRecursive, dwFlags);

    if (bRecursive)
    {
        DirScanner().ScanFolder(Reader(*this));
    }
    return m_hWatchEvent;
}

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

HANDLE FolderWatchInfo::Create(const CIRString& strPathName, DWORD dwFlags)
{
    CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);

    ASSERT(m_hWatchEvent == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);

    m_strPathName = CleanPathName(strPathName);
    m_dwFlags = dwFlags;
    m_hWatchEvent = FindFirstChangeNotification(m_strPathName, FALSE, dwFlags);
    DirScanner().ScanFolder(Reader(*this));
    return m_hWatchEvent;
}

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

void FolderWatchInfo::CloseHandle()
{
    CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);

    if (m_hWatchEvent != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FindCloseChangeNotification(m_hWatchEvent);
        m_hWatchEvent = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }
}

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

void FolderWatchInfo::ResetEvent()
{
    if (m_hWatchEvent != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hWatchEvent, 0))
        {
            if (!FindNextChangeNotification(m_hWatchEvent))
            {
                CloseHandle();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// *********************************************************************************************************************************

void FolderWatchInfo::AddToSubDirChangeList(CStringsVector& vSubDirs)
{
    CIRSingleLock lock(m_lock);

    if (WAIT_OBJECT_0 == WaitForSingleObject(m_hWatchEvent, 0))
    {
        ResetEvent();
        vSubDirs.push_back(m_strPathName);
    }
    for each (const FolderWatchInfoPtr& p in m_vChildren)
    {
        p->AddToSubDirChangeList(vSubDirs);
    }
}

// ***************************************************************************************************************************** EOF
```

Comment: Will this also work on symlinks within the watched tree? You are still watching one tree right?

Comment: I actually had a array of these to watch several 'library' folders, each with 100 or so subfolders.  You may have to add the symlinks manually, though.  The basic idea was to have as little wait events to wait on, and be as efficient as possible, this is part of a cache system, and I have other events to attend to.  It ended up working great in the end.  I never tested ResetEvent....  It looks funny.  Anyway, the 1000 ms delay was so I was sure I could reload files in the cache after an extrenal  change, you may not need it.

Comment: Could you give me a full working example including the array of some directories? I'm quite new to this and it makes it easier for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

filesystem send you notification only when files changed inside folder. symbolic link (or mount point) this is only file inside folder, which point to another file/folder. if target file/directory not inside our original folder - we and not get notification about changes inside this target folder

when you open direct symbolic link (or mount point) without `FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT` you really open target directory (to which point this symlink) and got notify from this directory

for got notification from some folder usually need do next:

- create class, which encapsulate folder handle and all data which you
  need for process notification from this directory (for example it
  full path, etc)
- open directory handle with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` for process
  [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) asynchronous
- call [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) for opened handle - as result
  you callback will be called when notification come from filesystem.
- first time direct call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx)
  and next time call it from callback (registered via
  [`BindIoCompletionCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx)) until we not got
  `ERROR_NOTIFY_CLEANUP`
- when we want stop notification process - need close directory handle.
  as result current active query will be just completed with
  `ERROR_NOTIFY_CLEANUP`
- need of course implement reference counting and handle rundown
  protection (for not use it after close) in class.

with this class we can have any count of directory spy - need simply create N instances of this class. nothing need wait, loops etc. simply continue do your task. when you no more need notification from directory - close it handle and release structure

simplest implementation:

```
class SPYDATA : public OVERLAPPED, RUNDOWN_REF
{
    HANDLE m_hFile;
    DWORD _dwNotifyFilter;
    LONG _dwRef;
    UCHAR _buf[PAGE_SIZE];

    ~SPYDATA()
    {
        Close();
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

    void DumpDirectoryChanges()
    {
        union {
            PVOID buf;
            PBYTE pb;
            PFILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION pfni;
        };

        buf = _buf;

        for (;;)
        {
            DbgPrint("[%03x] %x <%.*S>\n", _dwNotifyFilter, pfni->Action, pfni->FileNameLength >> 1, pfni->FileName);

            ULONG NextEntryOffset = pfni->NextEntryOffset;

            if (!NextEntryOffset)
            {
                break;
            }

            pb += NextEntryOffset;
        }
    }

    void IOCompletionRoutine(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        switch (dwErrorCode)
        {
        case ERROR_NOTIFY_CLEANUP:
            DbgPrint("%p>[%x] ---- NOTIFY_CLEANUP -----\n", this, _dwNotifyFilter);
            return ;
        case NOERROR:
            if (dwNumberOfBytesTransfered) DumpDirectoryChanges();
            DoRead();
            return;
        }

        DbgPrint("%p>[%x] error=%x\n", this, _dwNotifyFilter, dwErrorCode);
    }

    void IOCompletionRoutineAndRelease(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered)
    {
        IOCompletionRoutine(dwErrorCode, dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
        Release();
    }

    static VOID CALLBACK _IOCompletionRoutine(
        __in  DWORD status,
        __in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
        __in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
        )
    {
        static_cast<SPYDATA*>(lpOverlapped)->IOCompletionRoutineAndRelease(RtlNtStatusToDosError(status), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
    }

    virtual void RundownCompleted()
    {
        if (m_hFile) CloseHandle(m_hFile);
    }

public:

    void AddRef()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&_dwRef);
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!InterlockedDecrement(&_dwRef)) delete this;
    }

    SPYDATA(DWORD dwNotifyFilter) : _dwNotifyFilter(dwNotifyFilter)
    {
        _dwRef = 1;
        m_hFile = 0;
        RtlZeroMemory(static_cast<OVERLAPPED*>(this), sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

    void DoRead()
    {
        if (AcquireRundownProtection())
        {
            AddRef();

            ULONG dwErrorCode = ReadDirectoryChangesW(m_hFile, _buf, sizeof(_buf), 
                TRUE, _dwNotifyFilter, NULL, this, NULL) ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

            ReleaseRundownProtection();

            switch (dwErrorCode)
            {
            case NOERROR:
            case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
                break;
            default:
                IOCompletionRoutineAndRelease(dwErrorCode, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    ULONG Open(PCWSTR lpFileName )
    {
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(lpFileName, FILE_GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, 
            OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 0);

        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            if (BindIoCompletionCallback(hFile, _IOCompletionRoutine, 0))
            {
                m_hFile = hFile;

                return NOERROR;
            }
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }

        return GetLastError();
    }

    void Close()
    {
        BeginRundown();
    }
};

BOOL CreateSpy(DWORD dwNotifyFilter, PCWSTR lpFileName, SPYDATA** pp)
{
    if (SPYDATA* p = new SPYDATA(dwNotifyFilter))
    {
        ULONG dwError = p->Open(lpFileName);

        if (!dwError)
        {
            *pp = p;
            p->DoRead();
            return NOERROR;
        }

        p->Release();

        return dwError;
    }

    return ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;
}

void DestroySpyData(SPYDATA* p)
{
    if (p) 
    {
        p->Close();
        p->Release();
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
SPYDATA* p;
if (!CreateSpy(FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, L"<some path>", &p))
{
    MessageBoxW(0,0,0,0);// really here any code
    DestroySpyData(p);
}
```

my implementation of [rundown protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection) (it not implemented by api in user mode) is

```
#define RUNDOWN_INIT_VALUE 0x80000000
#define RUNDOWN_COMPLETE_VALUE 0
#define ObpBeginRundown(p) _interlockedbittestandreset(p, 31)
#define ObpUnlock _InterlockedDecrement

__forceinline BOOL ObpLock(PLONG pLock)
{
    LONG Value = *pLock, NewValue;

    for ( ; Value; Value = NewValue)
    {
        NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(pLock, Value + 1, Value);

        if (NewValue == Value) return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

__forceinline BOOL ObpAcquireRundownProtection(PLONG pLock)
{
    LONG Value = *pLock, NewValue;

    for ( ; Value < 0; Value = NewValue)
    {
        NewValue = _InterlockedCompareExchange(pLock, Value + 1, Value);

        if (NewValue == Value) return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

class __declspec(novtable) RUNDOWN_REF
{
    LONG _LockCount;

protected:

    virtual void RundownCompleted() = 0;

public:

    BOOL IsRundownBegin()
    {
        return 0 <= _LockCount;
    }

    __forceinline void Reinit()
    {
        if (InterlockedCompareExchange(&_LockCount, RUNDOWN_INIT_VALUE, RUNDOWN_COMPLETE_VALUE) != RUNDOWN_COMPLETE_VALUE)
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }
    }

    __forceinline RUNDOWN_REF()
    {
        _LockCount = RUNDOWN_INIT_VALUE;
    }

    __forceinline BOOL AcquireRundownProtection()
    {
        return ObpAcquireRundownProtection(&_LockCount);
    }

    __forceinline void ReleaseRundownProtection()
    {
        if (!_InterlockedDecrement(&_LockCount))
        {
            RundownCompleted();
        }
    }

    void BeginRundown()
    {
        if (AcquireRundownProtection())
        {
            ObpBeginRundown(&_LockCount);
            ReleaseRundownProtection();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This will stil monitor only one directory right? How can I monitor multiple directories at once ?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - of course no. this is monitoring any count of directories at once. simply call `CreateSpy(*_MASK, L"<some path>", &p)` **several time** - in what is problem ?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - you can use it for example next way: `SPYDATA* p = 0, *q = 0;
 CreateSpy(FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, L"*", &p);
 CreateSpy(FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, L"*", &q);
 /*do something*/
 DestroySpyData(q);
 DestroySpyData(p);`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - you also can use it in style - call and forget - if you not plan stop notification - just call `p->Release()` after no error call `CreateSpy` without `close()`

Comment: Ah oké great! I like it that I can call it in a function multiple times! I will give this a try

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - yes, can call multiple time and not only from same function. from different places. can exit from function from which you call `CreateSpy` and call `DestroySpyData` later from another place. between this you can do any - say be in windows message or console loop. call `CreateSpy` from windowproc, when handle some user message and `DestroySpyData` on another message. really no any restrictions

Comment: I get tons of errors implementing this code, what are the dependencies?

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - no any dependencies, what is first errors ?

Comment: This are some of the errors: 
`'PAGE_SIZE': undeclared identifier`
`'DbgPrint': identifier not found`
`'RtlNtStatusToDosError': identifier not found`
`'FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS': undeclared identifier`
`'FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK': undeclared identifier`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - `#define PAGE_SIZE 0x1000` (this from `wdm.h`) but you can use any value for `UCHAR _buf[PAGE_SIZE];` - say `UCHAR _buf[1024];`, `DbgPrint` - i use yourself for print, you can replace it to own print - which is better for you (this is only debug output, but not part of real code), [`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx) - and you need inlude `ntdll.lib`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - may be you need include `intrin.h` for `_interlockedbittestandreset` etc. but all is really simply resolved

Comment: please share me your DbgPrint function? I would like to be able to debug accordingly.

Comment: this is not my api, it exported from ntdll - `extern "C" WINBASEAPI
ULONG
__cdecl
DbgPrint (PCSTR Format,...);` again you need link with `ntdll.lib` (or `ntdllp.lib`) - [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543632(v=vs.85).aspx). however you can use `OutputDebugString`, print to console, c/c++ outstream etc

Comment: right. The errors that stay: 
`'RtlNtStatusToDosError': identifier not found`
`'FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS': undeclared identifier`
`'FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK': undeclared identifier`
`argument of type "PCWSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCSTR"`

Comment: `NTSYSAPI
ULONG
NTAPI
RtlNtStatusToDosError (
   _In_ NTSTATUS Status
   )` - this is definition for compiler, and for linker include `ntdll.lib` . `FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK` defined in `ntifs.h` but in what problem direct use yourself `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_*` flags. this is only demo - you may want look not for all notification anyway. `FILE_SHARE_*` if you not view definition of `FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS` . `PCWSTR` - i use unicode api only, when you use Ansi. so move my code to ansi or your to unicode..

Comment: I have only one error left now, which is:
`CreateFileA(LPCSTR,DWORD,DWORD,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,DWORD,DWORD,HANDLE)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'PCWSTR' to 'LPCSTR'`

Comment: but i say - i use `CreateFileW` and unicode strings with `L""` - you use obsolete `CreateFileA` and ansi strings `""` - so select or unicode or ansi. or `CreateFileW(L"some path", *)` or `CreateFileA("some path")`.

Comment: Right, I made it CreateFileW. However, now this error pops-up:
`unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) unsigned long __cdecl RtlNtStatusToDosError(long)" (__imp_?RtlNtStatusToDosError@@YAKJ@Z)`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - you need declare `RtlNtStatusToDosError` as "extern C" and `__stdcall` but not `__cdecl`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) unsigned long __stdcall RtlNtStatusToDosError(long)` and include ntdll.lib to linker input

Comment: I'm not very confident that this is going to work. I need a full working example, since I get extra errors on adding the extern "C" line such as: 
`a function declared 'dllimport' may not be defined`

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - code which i paste of course tested and worked. and this is full code. your problems only in weak knowledge inside c++, compiler,linker and winapi.  `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) unsigned long __stdcall RtlNtStatusToDosError(long);` - this is absolute correct definition for c++

Comment: Funny that the compiler complains about it right away than? The code isn't full at all. See the dependencies and linker settings you are passing later on? Just give me a full working code block, that would make it easier to understand instead of all these chunks

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - are you use *CL.exe* ? th *CL* compiler `extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) unsigned long __stdcall RtlNtStatusToDosError(long);` without any problems for me (if you not mistake in copy-paste). if you use another compiler - you need better know how import api (__declspec(dllimport) this is ms extension)